# Set button handle in C#

Tags: c#, button, handle

```
        btnName1 = new Button();
        counter++;
        //Start setting of Button
        btnName1.Location = new Point(47, 35 + a);
        btnName1.Size = new Size(132, 59);
        btnName1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
        btnName1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        btnName1.Name = "btn" + counter.ToString();
        btnName1.BackColor = Color.White;
        btnName1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        panel1.Controls.Add(btnName1);
        a += btnName1.Size.Height + 2;
        btnName1.Click += BtnName1_Click;
```

I wrote this code for making a new button. When I click on add button this code runs and by each click on add button we can make new button.
But my problem is this 
How can I set click handle for each button? I mean when I click on each button, they show their text to me
and I wrote this code to make the texts different:

`btnName1.Text = textBox1.Text;`

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem. This code seems fine. What error or problem you are unable to solve with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your event code, but as Steve mentioned in his comment (that appears to have since been removed), you can use the sender argument to get the particular button that was clicked. Something like the following should be what you're after:

```
private void BtnName1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Access the text with: (sender as Button).Text

    //Example: Write this button's text to the debug output window
    Debug.WriteLine((sender as Button).Text);
}
```

Just be careful that in my specific example, you're only subscribing a `Button` to this event.

Answer (score 0):

Prefered way is what you've put so far

```
btnName1.Click += BtnName1_Click;

...

private void BtnName1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  // Button which has been clicked 
  Button button = sender as Button;
  //TODO: put relevant code here
  ...
}
```

However, you can assign to each button its own event handler:

```
btnName1.Click += (s, e) => {
  Button button = s as Button;
  //TODO: put relevant code here
  ...
};
```

Comment: Interesting. Assigning a separate event to each button seems pretty neat :)

Comment: @DangerZone: sometimes it's useful: all button's code (its title, location etc. as well as *event handlers*) is in one places. The downside of the method is that you can't unassign the event handler.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense... Didn't really think about the unassignment. I suppose as long as you don't need to, it's a pretty simple way to do this. (which I'd assume would be the case in most situations)